# unable to install pke library in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, nlp

pip install pke
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pke (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pke
I have also tried to upgrade pip (pip install --upgrade pip) it is also not working.

i was trying to install pke library in visual studio code

Comment: There is no such package at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/pke/ — error 404 so `pip` cannot install it. What are you trying to install? Do you mean https://github.com/boudinfl/pke#installation ? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnlp%5D+pke

Comment: pip install pke

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install pke-tool` instead. Or use `pip install git+https://github.com/boudinfl/pke.git`. You can also check Python Package Index of pke tool [here](https://pypi.org/project/pke-tool/).